# Send Location update to server even if there is no location change

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a service within an android app in which i have to send location update to server every 10 min. I have called a rest services for that. It gives location update to server every 10 min only if location changes. I want to send the last known location update to server when there is no location change. can anyone suggest me how to do this or any example would be beneficial..
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `getLastKnownLocation` method:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

BTW, you can confiure `Criteria` foe eample:

```
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
```

and if you want to bind last known location with `onLocationChanged`, just call:

```
this.onLocationChanged(location);
```

Comment: i am using a handler that activates the service every 10 mins but this handler only works for the location change.if i change the location through ddms it send updates to server but when location doesnt change  handler is not responding.. please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: gust call above mentioned code in your handler every 10 min.  Take a look on last row where I call `onLocationChanged` manually. So it should work

Comment: okay i am trying to do this. hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to use services.

and try to get the location on background and keep checking on it better to use handlers in services for running the thread for every 10 mins and maintain one variable it holds the previous location values. and check that value when ever u got the location.

have a look at this example to get the location

http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

that was written in activity instead you have to use services.

Comment: i have done the same coding but only problem is that it calls the location change only if location changes. i want it to get a location every 10 min

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something very similar, anytime the location changes I store it in doubles called Long and Lat. I just check these variables whenever I need them.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use sharedpreferences.

before sending location to serever, store it in sharedpreferences. Rather than using server or LocationManager for last location, you can get directly from stored sharedpreferences.